# the variable changed unexpected in my assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

my system is ubuntun 16.04 32bits nasm

I wrote a code which take an input "str_a str_b",and it will give you the length of str_a and length of str_b.

However if I input"1 1",length of str_a supposed to be 1,but when I output it ,it was 3.If I input "11 11",the output just became 5,this almost drive me crazy.
And I try to print an "a" when increase length of str_a when it is"1 1",it was just printed for one time.

here is the core code

```
begin_input_and_stroge:
    ;input
    pusha
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, input  
    mov edx, 50    
    int 80h

    mov byte[len_a],0
    mov byte[len_b],0
    mov edx,0
    mov ecx,0
set_num_a:
    cmp byte[input+edx]," " ;if meet " ",it will start calculate length of b
    je set_num_b_ini
    inc byte[len_a]
    inc edx
    inc ecx
    jmp set_num_a
set_num_b_ini:
    mov ecx,0
set_num_b:
    cmp byte[input+edx],0
    je finish_input_and_stroge
    inc byte[len_b]
    inc edx
    inc ecx
    jmp set_num_b
finish_input_and_stroge:
    dec byte[len_b]
    popa
    ret
```

and it is the whole file,because I tried to do something else,it look quite ugly

```
section .data                ;Data segment
    rev_a TIMES 23 db 0
    rev_b TIMES 23 db 0  
    text db  "split"
    space db " "
    string db '===========', 0Ah
    length equ 13
;rev_a the reverse array of a ,[3,2,1]
;num_a the string of a [1,2,3]
;len_a the length of num_a        
section .bss           ;Uninitialized data    
   copy_text resb 50
   input resb 50
   len_a resb 0
   len_b resb 0
   num_a resb 23
   num_b resb 23
   flag resb 0
   output_len resb 10
   print_test resb 10

     

section .text          ;Code Segment
    global _start
    
_start:                

    call begin_input_and_stroge
    mov ecx,0
    mov al,byte[len_a]
    add al,"0"
    mov byte[print_test+ecx],al
    call output

    mov al,"0"
    mov byte[print_test+ecx],al
    call output
    ; mov al,"0"
    ; mov byte[print_test],al
    ; call output


    ; mov al,byte[len_b]
    ; add al,"0"
    ; mov byte[print_test],al
    ; call output

    
    
    ; mov edx,0
    ; mov ecx,0
    ; mov ecx,dword[len_a]
    ; dec ecx
    ; output_num_a:
    ;     cmp ecx,0
    ;     je finish_output_num_a
    ;     mov al,byte[num_a+ecx]
    ;     mov byte[print_test+edx],al
    ;     inc edx
    ;     dec ecx
    ; jmp output_num_a
    ; finish_output_num_a:
    ; call output

   ; Exit code
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

output:
    pusha
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, print_test
    mov edx, 10
    int 80h
    popa
    ret

begin_input_and_stroge:;输入 ，并将其存储进字符串，同时记录相应的长度
    ;input
    pusha
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, input  
    mov edx, 50    
    int 80h

    mov byte[len_a],0
    mov byte[len_b],0
    mov edx,0
    mov ecx,0
set_num_a:
    cmp byte[input+edx]," ";若是空格，开始给num_b设置值
    je set_num_b_ini
    ; mov al,byte[input+edx]
    ; sub al,"0"
    ; mov byte[num_a+ecx],al
    inc byte[len_a]
    
    ; mov al,"a"
    ; mov byte[print_test],al
    ; call output

    inc edx
    inc ecx
    jmp set_num_a
set_num_b_ini:
    mov ecx,0
set_num_b:
    cmp byte[input+edx],0
    je finish_input_and_stroge
    ; mov al,byte[input+edx]
    ; sub al,"0"
    ; mov byte[num_b+ecx],al
    inc byte[len_b]
    inc edx
    inc ecx
    jmp set_num_b
finish_input_and_stroge:
    dec byte[len_b];len_b减去1
    popa
    ret
```

Comment: `len_a resb 0` does not do what you think it does. It allocates zero bytes of storage, not a single byte initialized to zero. Change it to `resb 1`. Check other lines for similar mistakes. Also note that input is not necessarily zero terminated and it likely includes a line feed.

Comment: Don't forget to inspect your data as part of debugging.  The layout of the variables, their values, and addresses..  We should verify the initial data before beginning single step debugging.  If that data is wrong, there's no way for the program to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> len_a resb 0
> len_b resb 0
> num_a resb 23
> ```

Because `resb 0` does not reserve any bytes at all, those 3 labels actually point to the same memory byte. The code is equivalent to:

```
len_a:
len_b:
num_a resb 23
```

Therefore the increments that you apply to *len_a* and *len_b* will add up. That's why you get the unexpected results. What you need is `len_a resb 1` `len_b resb 1`.

---

> ```
> dec byte[len_b]
> popa
> ret
> ```

This is an ugly and probably last minute correction on the *len_b* variable for another problem with the *begin_input_and_stroge* routine. When the *set_num_a* loop has found a space character and you transition to the *set_num_b* loop, you really should skip that character (`inc edx`) instead of comparing it to the final zero byte. Because that " " <> 0, the `cmp` is certain to fall through in an unwanted `inc byte [len_b]`.

I the below code I removed the operations on `ECX` that were redundant:

```
    ...
    xor edx, edx
    mov [len_b], dl
set_num_a:
    cmp byte [input+edx], " "
    je  set_num_b_ini
    inc edx
    jmp set_num_a

set_num_b_ini:
    mov [len_a], dl
    inc edx          ; Skip the " "
set_num_b:
    cmp byte [input+edx], 0
    je  finish_input_and_stroge
    inc byte [len_b]
    inc edx
    jmp set_num_b
finish_input_and_stroge:
    popa
    ret
```

---

In the commented-out section you have a line that reads:

```
; mov ecx,dword[len_a]
```

Be extra careful with the sizes that you use. If you define the *len_a* variable as **byte**, you need to use it that way consistently throughout the program. If you need to load the **dword** register `ECX` from that byte-sized variable you can use `MOVZX`:

```
movzx ecx, byte [len_a]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. fix my problem and give so many  constructive advice,it help me a lot